How to read/retrieve section break("Next Page") in Word using office.js
I have a requirement to analyze(read) section breaks in a Word document, specifically to determine whether they are "Next Page" or "Continuous." Based on section break "Next Page", I need to break the document into sections accordingly.
Is there an existing method or feature available in Office.js or any plans to introduce such functionality for reading and working with section breaks programmatically in Word documents?

I am afraid so far you can insert a section break, but so far not able to get all section break types. such as Next page.
